# 1-d pointer to a 2-d array

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>

void display(int (*p)[3],int,int);

int main()
{
    int a[3][4] = {1,2,3,4,
                   5,6,7,8,
                   9,0,1,6};

    display(a,3,4);
}

void display(int (*p)[3],int r,int c)
{
    int i,j,*q;
    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        q=p+i;
        for(j=0;j<c;j++)
        printf("%d",*(q+j));
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

this does not work but if we write 
void dis(int (*p)[4],int,int);
it works
that is if we have a pointer of array having number of columns as number of element in array

Comment: Sorry. I posted it by mistake

Comment: @exnihilo I would have deleted the question but I am not able to.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays used in expressions with rare exceptions are converted to pointers to their first element.

From the C Standard (6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators)

> 3 Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary &
>   operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an
>   expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an
>   expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial
>   element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object
>   has register storage class, the behavior is undefined.

So if you have an array declared like

```
T a[N];
```

where `T` is some type and `N` is some integral expression then the array can be converted to a pointer the following way.

First of all let's rewrite the declaration the following way

```
T ( a[N] );
```

Now to get pointer just substitute the declarator in the parentheses `a[N]` for `*p`. For example

```
T ( a[N] );
T ( *p ) = a;
```

So if you have a multidimensional array like this

```
T a[N1][N2];
```

then pointer to its first element can be defined the following way

```
T ( a[N1] )[N2];
T ( *p )[N2] = a;
```

In general case you can use the rule

```
T a[N1][N2]...[Nn];
```

is equivalent to

```
T ( a[N1] )[N2]...[Nn];
```

and a pointer is defined like

```
T ( a[N1] )[N2]...[Nn];
T ( * p )[N2]...[Nn] = a;
```

In your program you have the declaration

```
int a[3][4] = {1,2,3,4,
    5,6,7,8,
    9,0,1,6};
```

that can be rewritten as it has been shown above like

```
int ( a[3] )[4] = {1,2,3,4,
    5,6,7,8,
    9,0,1,6};
```

So the pointer to the first element of the array will have the type `int ( * )[4]`
Thus the function shall be declared at least like

```
void display( int (*)[4], int, int);
```

Take into account that within the function

```
void display(int (*p)[4],int r,int c)
{
    int i,j,*q;
    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        q=p+i;
        for(j=0;j<c;j++)
        printf("%d",*(q+j));
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

there is an assignment of incompatible types

```
q=p+i;
```

The expression `p + i` has the type `int ( * )[4]` while the pointer `q` has the type `int *`.

It shall be written

```
q = *( p + i );
```

In this case the expression `*( p + i )` has the type `int[4]` that is implicitly converted to pointer of the type `int *`

Also according to the C Standard the function `main` without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

If to use only pointers instead of indices to access elements of the array then the function can look the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define COLS    4

void display( int (*)[COLS], size_t );

int main( void )
{
    int a[][COLS] = 
    {
        { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
        { 5, 6, 7, 8 },
        { 9, 0, 1, 6 }
    };

    const size_t ROWS = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    display( a, ROWS);
}

void display( int (*p)[COLS], size_t rows )
{
    for ( int ( *p_row )[COLS] = p; p_row != p + rows; ++p_row )
    {
        for ( int *p_col = *p_row; p_col != *p_row + COLS; ++p_col )
        {
            printf( "%d ", *p_col );
        }

        putchar( '\n' );
    }
}
```

Its output is

```
1 2 3 4 
5 6 7 8 
9 0 1 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays naturally decays to pointers to their first element. That is, `a` will decay to a pointer to `a[0]`, i.e. `&a[0]`.

And what is `a[0]`? It's an array of *four* `int` elements. So `&a[0]` is a pointer to an array of four `int` elements, or `int (*)[4]`.

Answer (score 0):

You should write  void display(int (*p)[4],int,int) exactly like that.
because when you write int a[3][4]  c see this like three pointers to 3 arrays of 4 elements each.